# Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression in MS-Access

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I am using Excel-VBA to insert data into a table. I have a .csv file that was parsed and used to create an insert string. I am using it on multiple tables in a row. The first table processes fine, but the second one gives me an error:

Run-time error '-2147217913 (8004e07)':
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

After researching this, it appears that I am trying to pass data in a bad form, but I'm not seeing where or how, as the first table processed. The final insert string that fails looks like:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name VALUES ('Text_entry', 'Long_Integer_entry', 'Double_entry', '')
```

**EDIT:**
I just tried another test and found the problem: any field that is a Double or Single Integer that gets passed the null '' causes the error. How do I pass a null value to these data types?

Comment: Have you tried with double quotes? Is `Table_Name` expecting strings for `Long_Integer_entry` and `Double_entry`? If not, remove the quotes there - quotes are used to delimit `String` values, not numbers.

Comment: Does that mean if it is a number I have to omit all kinds of quotes?

Comment: That's what I said

Comment: It is expecting the data type that I pseudo named the values being passed to it. I just tried another test and found the problem: any field that is a Double or Single Integer that gets passed the null '' causes the problem. How do I pass a null value to these data types?

Comment: change your table fields to allow nulls or set the nulls as zero before inserting.

Comment: Is that something I have to do in Access or can I do that through VBA as well while I am creating a new table? Is this only a problem for Doubles or all Number data types?

Comment: "set the nulls as zero before inserting" is a terrible idea. Zero is a value

Comment: The first question you should be asking is "is a null value in my input data valid, or is the CSV file I am using corrupt"?

Comment: You can apply the function here to take care of this: [CSql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728268/ms-access-2007-update-number-with-commas-fails/38740064#38740064)

Comment: The data I am using is not corrupt. The null values are either records that have no applicable entry for that column, or there is no current entry on it. Does it matter if I use Null instead of a zero length string for string data type entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you can append and update `NULL` in any data type column including string, numeric, or datetime values. So simply pass it in your append query. Be sure not to quote it as it is neither a string or numeric value. The `NULL` entity means an unknown value.

```sql
INSERT INTO Table_Name VALUES ('Text_entry', 'Long_Integer_entry', 'Double_entry', NULL)
```

Specifically, your attempted `''` is actually a zero-length string (a non-NULL value) which is why it failed to work in a number column.

Should you use parameterized queries, also pass VBA's `Null` to bind to SQL statement:

```vb
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table_Name VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd
     .ActiveConnection = conn
     .CommandText = strSQL
     .CommandType = adCmdText
     .CommandTimeout = 15
End With

' BINDING PARAMETERS
cmd.Parameters.Append _
      cmd.CreateParameter("textparam", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "Text_entry")
cmd.Parameters.Append _
      cmd.CreateParameter("longtxtparam", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "Long_Integer_entry")
cmd.Parameters.Append _
      cmd.CreateParameter("doubleparam", adDouble, adParamInput, , "Double_entry")
cmd.Parameters.Append _
      cmd.CreateParameter("nullparam", adDouble, adParamInput, , Null)
```

Comment: Using the "Null" keyword got the Doubles and Long Integers to process correctly, thank you! Is there a downside to using Null for strings instead of using a zero length string?

Comment: Great to hear! Storage-wise, I don't know if it makes a difference. `NULL` tend to symbolize uninitialized values where as a zero-length string is a legitimate initialized value. Queries will differ and are not interchangeable: `[str] IS NULL` vs `[str] = ''`. All in all, it depends on your operations, akin to storing 0 or NULL for numbers.